# Why do I have a decimal error when writing data to MS Access via Matlab?

Tags: matlab, ms-access, rounding, numeric

I write numeric data to MS Access tables. All the tables have the same numeric fields format (ie 'real simple', 'standard', 'auto'). I push numbers via Matlab in the tables and MS Access rounds numbers to the 1rst decimal and i can't modify it.

Does someone know ?

Screenshots there :

http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1526721/logiciels/microsoft-office/access/ihm/formatage-champ-numerique-2-decimales/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rounding a  trailing 0 (zero) is not rounding.

What you miss is the format that displays the number. Where you do this, set number of decimals to two.

Comment: Thanks you're right it's a display pb. 
In MS Access 2013 in my installation (Office 365, MS DB Engine x64) I changed to "réel double" (french) and all the digits appeared. It's basic pb has finally got me hours. I feel like i'm a MS Access Dumb owner :-)